# Apple Push Notifications not received in iOS 9/10 after switching it on Capabilities

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios9, ios10

I've tried to adapt my application to iOS 10, but I am facing issues with push notification. I have tested push in two devices with iOS 9 and iOS 10. In my application in Capabilities push notification does not switch on, but application work fine in iOS 8 and iOS 9, but in iOS 10 i can't take token with error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"

I switched on Push Notification in Capabilities, and push Notifications works, sometimes it works fine in iOS 10, but next morning, I tested it on iOS 9 device and it did not work, I switched to iOS 10 device and push is not working on it as well, I went back to old version, without turning on Capabilities and it works fine in iOS 9 device, but in iOS 10 does not (token).
I tried removing and download provisional profiles, remove all cache in Xcode, erase devices, I tried [Push notification issue with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top) 
but it did not worked.
How can i fix it ??

Comment: please check your certificate & capability in project.

Comment: in iOS 9 device with XCode 8 and turned off Push Notification in Capabilities push come very well

Comment: hi @Sergio I had similar issue with iOS 10. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I'm having this issue too, pushes now work on iOS 10 but not iOS 9

Comment: @VirenRajput no i don`t, it work in testflight, but no in XCode, i testing my push in iOS 9 device with switch off Push Notification(XCode 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution, in my case: Before iOS 10 we used only Production sertificate to test push, it work fine, but after iOS 10 pushes do not receive in app runing with Xсode(but receive in TestFlight), after we create and use developer certificate to sign pushes - it work again