# silent push notifications in ios10

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios10

Hi i was stucked in silent notifications in ios10

1. i gave support to ios 10 as said in this link
   [Push notification issue with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top)
2. it is working fine in iphone 6 (calling background fetch completion handler)
3. when it comes to iphone 5 device not working properly
4. when i push silent notification device in background not responding completion handler why i didn't understand

Comment: Make sure iPhone 5 is using same iOS version