# UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods not being called Xcode 8 iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, push, usernotifications

I have followed all the steps exactly as mentioned here: [Push notification issue with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top). But unfortunately, these two methods are not being called:

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
```

The only method called is:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

However, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called when app is closed.

I am using Xcode version 8 and iOS 10.0.2

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder   <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     if( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" ) )
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound |    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if( !error )
         {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];  // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
             NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
             NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
             NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );  
         }  
     }];  
}
return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{


if( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO( @"10.0" ) )
{
    NSLog( @"iOS version >= 10. Let NotificationCenter handle this one." );
    // set a member variable to tell the new delegate that this is background
    return;
}
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

NSLog(@"Userinfo %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);

completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{

//Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.

NSLog(@"Userinfo %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);

}
```

Besides, I get an error if I call return in didReceiveRemoteNotification:

Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

When I see iOS console (a tool to get more logs of push notification), I can see this error:

```
20/10/16 15:06:48 SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[55]: Not saving push notification to store 3995-06A9, error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1401 "Notification has no user-facing content" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notification has no user-facing content}
```

Comment: can you show that appdelegate code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik now appdelegate code is there! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP).*

The push notification was missing alert key in aps, so User Notifications Server was not saving notification in the store and hence these two methods were not being called.