# codename one push notifications not registering on ios 10

Tags: ios, push-notification, codenameone

I've recently been trying to add push to a codename one app following the guide here:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pushing-it.html

Everything is working on Android but on iOS none of the callbacks are being fired after registering for push.

it may have something to do with this issue:
[Push notification issue with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't use xcode 8.x yet (still updating to 7.x) so this doesn't impact us. Did you check the "Include push" flag?

Does your provisioning profile include push?

Comment: They have slightly changed the apn certificated in developer.apple so I did need to add a separate development apn. Now the app is asking for push permission, However; none of the callbacks defined by the PushCallback interface are ever being called.  
I thought it may have had something to do with logs being blocked, but even trying to show result as a popup shows nothing.

Comment: Do you have a pro account?

Comment: Turns out it was the push flag above, in addition to a server issue I'd introduced. I was trying to prevent multiple users having the same deviceID so iterated through them all. I'd forgotten to exclude the current user, so no deviceID was ever stored.  
I still find it strange that no log statements seem to be appearing from the callbacks on ios.

Comment: What log statements would you expect from us in a situation like that?

Comment: What I'm say is the logs that I've put in my app are apparently not being output on iOS 10. The push registration is working but I thought it wasn't because none of my logs were getting written. If I had to guess I would say it maybe because it's a background thread which isn't allowed to log output?

Comment: That's unlikely. How are you reading the Logs? Are you using Log.sendLog() or are you using a cable?

Comment: On a mac in xcode>devices. It always worked this way in the past

Comment: Looks like apple had a bug with version 10 or 10.1 of iOS where they had left their debugging system on. This was apparently flooding the logs and preventing our apps from outputting logs. It may be fixed in 10.2