# iOS 10 push notifications not showing

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios10

So, I have been stuck for a while now. I have implemented everything like here [Push notification issue with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top). I have added Push notifications and background modes to device capabilities. I can see that I am getting my device token. On devices with iOS 9 and below, push notifications are working. Do you know, besides new capabilities options and notification framework, is there anything else what I need to do to get push notifications on iOS 10? Provision profile and App Id is ok, it has aps environment, but that's now in its own file.

Comment: After installing the app. Have you restarted the device?. It seems a bug in iOS 10 until you restart your device, push notification doesn't works.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use the development certificate if you load the app using Xcode, production if you downloaded it through the app store. I have not found a way around this. Try setting your APNs provider to development.

Comment: It's funny, because I can see them coming in my development in foreground, or when I open an app and they are immediately processed, but they are not showing as a banner or alert.

Comment: Experiencing similar issue: delegate method can print the notification in the console but no badge, alert or sound is being displayed on the iPhone device screen.  Did anyone resolve this?  Certificiates for development and distribution are OK, and am working with Firebase to issue notification message.

Comment: Same issue banner or alert is not showing.Did you find any solution of that?@MikeLondonUK @Flipper