# Registering for Push notifications functions don't get called

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm making this sweet app that requires Push notifications.

However when trying to grab the Push token not all required functions seem to get executed.

The user does get presented with this Alert:

[image]

When the user hits OK I step through my code and see that not everything gets executed:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    let tapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action:#selector(UIView.endEditing))
    tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapper)
    
    print("gets called")
    registerForPushNotifications(UIApplication.sharedApplication())
}

func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
    print("gets called")
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
        forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    print("doesn't get called")
    if notificationSettings.types != .None {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    print("doesn't get called")
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var apnsTokenString = ""
    
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        apnsTokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }
    
    Constant.pushToken = apnsTokenString
    
    print("Device Token:", Constant.pushToken)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    debugPrint("Error Registering Remote Notification")
}
```

In my console the following gets printed:

> gets called
>
> gets called

Meaning that not all required functions get called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not calling didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken func right ?     Refer this Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10/39506524#39506524

Comment: Nope, that one does NOT get called. And that is exactly the function that I need to get called.

Comment: okay, Follow the step which given in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10/39506524#39506524

Comment: I've tried but not really helpful. I'm programming for iOS 9+ so I cannot use that framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of the code you posted in your question is in your view controller class, the problem is that you need to put the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods in your actual app delegate class, not the view controller class. Simply move those methods to the proper class and they will work.

Comment: You mean moving the bottom 3 functions to the AppDelegate.swift class right?

Comment: Yes, that is it exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    print("gets called")
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)

          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
          application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}



func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

          let characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")

          let deviceTokenString: String = (deviceToken.description as NSString)
               .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(characterSet)
               .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "") as String
         print(deviceTokenString)
     }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The second function does not get called.

Comment: You need to call in App Delegate only