# Silent Local Notifications in iOS 10

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, ios10

Does anyone know how to send a silent **Local** Notification in iOS 10?

This worked nicely in iOS 7/8/9 but it doesn't seem possible in iOS 10. All I had to do was create a notification and leave the `Body` empty (typically making it silent)

If I leave the `Body` of the notification as an empty string in iOS 10, then the notification does not fire at all. If I put something into the Body and the app is in the background, it presents a notification banner to the user - which is not what I want.

Is there another way to do this or have I missed something?

I am using the Xamarin.iOS platform but I imagine the resolution will be the same on Swift/Objective-C so any responses will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10

Comment: I've faced the same problem. and looking for the solution.

Comment: I ended up setting a fake sound to play.  It needs a Body, Badge or Sound before it delivers. We are obviously missing something fundamental in the new UNNotification system.