# iOS 10 Push Notifications - Sandbox APNS Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, ios10

I am noticing a weird push notifications issue with iOS 10. I have done suggested code changes in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10) to receive pushes form sandbox APNS.

After making these changes I am getting device token back from APNS and able to receive the notifications. However, if I kill & re-launch the application from Xcode again, pushes do not work. If I delete the app from the device and put it again from Xcode, pushes start coming.

Anyone have seen this behaviour and know about the possible fix would be really helpful. Please advise.

Here is the step by step implementation in my `AppDelegate`:

**Step 1: Import UserNotifications**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
```

**Step 2: Conform to notification protocol**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate() <UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

**Step 3: In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: register for notification`**

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"10")) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
            center.delegate = self;
            [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if( !error ){
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                }
            }];
        }
```

**Step 4: Finally handle the push notification**

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {
    [self handlePushNotificationWithUserInfo:response.notification.request.content.userInfo];
}
```

Comment: r u registered your device token

Comment: Never faced this issue. Try resetting the simulator.

Comment: I received the push token, handed over to my server and it is registered at server side. They are sending push payload as well.

Comment: can you show ur appdelegate code

Comment: Please check your Device token is properly registered or correct ? How you are testing Push for Sandbox APNS ?

Comment: Do you register every time when app launch or only once ?

Comment: see this once my bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: I am doing test on device and is registering every time I launch the application. We are using sandbox push certificate on server side to send payload. I believe token is registered correctly as I get notification on delete app & re-launch.

Comment: Ok. In which state of your app, when you receive notifications ?

Comment: Its in foreground state.

Comment: Try checking to send notification again when your app in foreground state. And If possible then try to communicate with backend developer to verify that notification sent from by them or not. Or you should try Pusher app to test without backend. here is pusher app code. https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

Comment: Just use the .app file. Add device token, select your sandbox certificate, and try to send notification.

Comment: ok, let me try that @Wolverine. Much thanks for the direction. One observation while I was doing some research. After I implemented `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method, probability of push receipt has been increased. I am still missing notification though. On delete and re-install, I get it 100% of the times.

Comment: For iOS 10, there are 2 methods. One is **didReceiveNotificationResponse**is Handle push from background or closed. And another is **willPresentNotification** Handle push from foreground.

Comment: I think you are missing to implement **willPresentNotification**

Comment: Indeed @Wolverine. Could you please put this in answer and I shall accept it. The only callout here is if I call completion block then it present both my custom notification as well as system notification from top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle notifications in **iOS 10**.

There are two methods.

> willPresentNotification

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center  
  willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification  
  withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler  
{  
   NSLog( @"This method is called to Handle push from foreground" );  
  // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground  
    NSLog(@"User info ==> %@", notification.request.content.userInfo);
}
```

> And didReceiveNotificationResponse

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center  
  didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response  
  withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler  
{  
     NSLog( @"Handle push from background or closed" );  
     NSLog(@"%@", response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
}
```

Hope it helps..!!