# FCM Refreshed token and push notification not receiving in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm using FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) for sending push notifications in iOS.
The code is running fine in iOS 9.3, and I received the Push notification and refreshed token in it.

But in iOS 10, it is not receiving the FCM refreshed token and also not receiving the Push notification.
I have also searched it out, and written code for UNUserNotificationCenter. And also implemented its delegate functions, I have followed the following link, [Push notification issue with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top)
but still in vain.
Kindly help me to resolve this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What logs are you getting from fem instead of Instance id?

Comment: @ahmad Can you please share the code??
Also check if you are using correct API key and provisioning profile and certificates.

Comment: @himanth, I am getting logs for iOS 9.3 as this: https://cloudup.com/c6KnS3sNPxM

while for iOS 10, I am getting logs as this: https://cloudup.com/cVAy2JJpdCE

Comment: @CodeGuru, I am using the same Provisioning profile an certificate for iOS 10, which I am using for iOS 9.3. Everything works fine for iOS 9.3
Please see this : https://cloudup.com/c6KnS3sNPxM

But for iOS 10, I am not getting refreshed token. 
Please also see this: https://cloudup.com/cVAy2JJpdCE

Comment: @CodeGuru, This is the dropbox Link for my code of AppDelegate files
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dm0f1mglrwmlojo/AABHu9uGRWvF9bPjiM_DTHU4a?dl=0

Comment: Please any help, I am waiting for the response.