# My URL isn't running after I tap on my notification action. What do I do?

Tags: ios, swift, url, unusernotificationcenter, usernotifications

In my app, I want a `URL` to run when my *notification* action is tapped on. The problem is that when I run the *app* it puts me into the foreground but doesn't run the `URL` (I added `.foreground` to the *notification* action). Here is my code:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.actionIdentifier == "call" {


           if let urled = URL(string: "tel://1234567891") {
                UIApplication.shared.open(urled, options: [:])                            
            }                

    }


}
}
```

Anyones help would be great:) Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Where does the variable `number` get set or accessed?  I don't see any reference to it anywhere.

Comment: @creeperspeak the variable `number` is set right above the function, I just didn't want to share any phone numbers

Comment: OK, have you confirmed that the `if let urled` is passing?  You can try calling `canOpenUrl` to see if the url is a valid format.  Have you tried printing `"tel://\(number)"` to see if it looks right?  If `number` is an optional you'll need to unwrap it first too.  Could be a lot of things, but print statements and breakpoints could solve the problem for you.

Comment: @creeperspeak normally I don't have a variable called `number` there, because this app is just a testing app, normally I have a typical string right there. I've tested using this url many times and it works I just can't figure out how to get it to work when the notification action is tapped on.

Comment: Try `canOpenUrl` just to be sure, and put a breakpoint at `if response...` and just step through the code one line at a time to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10 :
Add UserNotifications.framework to your app.
Please check that you have set delegate for push notification.
if you have already set it then try following method for iOS 10.

```
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
}



 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("Handle push from foreground")
    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

 print("Handle push from background or closed")

  // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background

print("\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")

}
```

Comment: Please review this link for Objective C : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

if response.actionIdentifier == "call" {

    if let urled = URL(string: "tel://\(1234567891)") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urled) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(urled, options: [:], completionHandler: { (completed) in
                // completionHandler block
             }) 
         }
     } 
 }
completionHandler()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing and I am facing the same issue.

You can try an alternative solution if you are using **Notification Content Extension**.

Since **we can handle the notification actions in both `Extension` as well as `Containing App`**, you can try handling it in `Extension` using `extensionContext` instead of `Containing App's UIApplication object`.

**Try this:**

```
    func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void)
    {
        if response.actionIdentifier == "call"
        {
            self.extensionContext?.open(URL(string: "tel:9555221836")!, completionHandler: { (done) in
                completion(.dismiss)
            })
        }
        //Handling other actions...
    }
```